# Lock record while updating in oracle database

Tags: php

I have table `user` with fields let say `userid`,`username`,`email`,`dob`, and i have to do CRUD operation on this table.
I have done all the CRUD operations and everything is working perfectly fine. But it lacks one feature i.e. while a particular record is fetched by user for update other user can't do update,delete on it.

```
SELECT *  
FROM USER
WHERE USERID=2
FOR UPDATE OF EMAIL NOWAIT;
```

I have this query but it seems not to be good approach because the lock is not released until the `commit` is fired.

Is there any better approach for this problem.

Comment: Select for update only when you actually are going to change it. However, check that the latest value is the same as when you fetched it (displayed it) initially. If it is different then someone else changed it before you.

Comment: this is the correct behavior  .., is locked  for your update  until youir  commit

Comment: @RyanVincent but what i need is that if someone select the record for update and other user is trying to fetch the same record for update/delete then it show alert him that it is being locked by some other user. Please wait untill he updates

Comment: @scaisEdge what if user fetches the record for update and then he wishes not to update it. Then i have fire commit as well without the update being done isn't??

Comment: The select for update  should performed  when the action is clearly oriented  to preserve the record  for an imminent update .. this is the way oracle select for update work .. you can perform the select for update mor late as possible  .. you don't need  select for update  a lot of time before you effectively execute update ....

Comment: The time windows is very small. I would not use 'nowait' I suspect the queue of concurrent requsts to update the email will be very small. All the user will notice is a slight response delay sometimes.

Comment: @scaisEdge lets drop the thought that i am locking any record or something.However i need to prevent second user from selecting the record. if first user has requested it for update

Comment: @RyanVincent the email is just for example i need to block entire row from being fetched for update by second uder

Comment: @scaisEdge If i store in global session that userid=5 is being updated by some user so whenever second user try to fetch the record it will first check in session whether it is being used by someone else if not then it will return the data else error

Comment: the session is not global .. is local .. for broswer ..

Comment: So, just block. The PHP transaction will be quite short. what is happening. You lock the record. Try and do your updates / changes. If all ok commit. If not all ok report the errors. Total time to do this is small fractions of second as it is done in a PHP transaction.

Comment: @Abhishek   what say Ryan Vincent in commet is right ..

Comment: @RyanVincent i too agree with him but the issue is suppose a user fetched a record for update at 12:00 and he make some changes and submits form at 12:10 then for the duration of that 10 min no one should fetch the record for update and delete. So its a not a fraction of second thing.

Comment: @scaisEdge yeh i got that session is not global its per user, i will figure out any global approach but considering i have find out global approach then would that method make sense??

Comment: No. That is not how it is done.You never lock records with the intent of changing them  maybe sometime in the future. What if the user get interrupted  or goes to lunch? You try and do the changes now. If the information is `out of date` then you show the user the latest information so that they can find out why it is not as expected.

Comment: I found out some article which explains my problem and there is solution as well. is the approach right in the [blog](http://www.programmingunit.com/2013/11/03/lock-a-record-php-mysql-modification/) @RyanVincent

Comment: @scaisEdge please check above link and check if its right way to do?